# A batch file for ADB push using the "Send to" windows shortcut

Tags: adb, sendto

Let's say I want a batch file to do adb push to a fixed folder on android but I want it to get the path of a file through the "Send to" shortcut on the context menu of Windows. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to make it work by adding a shortcut pointing to this batch file to shell:sendto. Now I want to change it so that there will be fixed options to where the file will be pushed like option A to be /storage/sdcard1/ADB and option B would be /sdcard/ADB

```
@echo off
adb push "%~f1" /storage/sdcard1/ADB
pause
```